# Returning multiple attributes from a document lookup in XSLT/XPATH

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have a XML lookup document and hopefully trying to make it a little faster to execute. I repeatedly lookup a document to return different attributes, it is possible to return all the attributes in a single lookup and just parse the returned value? Sample code:

```
            <xsl:attribute name="Oracle_Routing">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc)/@OracleSchema"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="TableName">
                <xsl:value-of
                select="key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc)/@DestinationTable"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:variable name="Column"
            select="key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc)/@ColumnName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly store `<xsl:variable name="referenced-node" select="key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc)"/>` and then use e.g.

```
        <xsl:attribute name="Oracle_Routing">
            <xsl:value-of select="$referenced-node/@OracleSchema"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
```

instead of

```
        <xsl:attribute name="Oracle_Routing">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc)/@OracleSchema"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
```

and so on. (As a side note, I would suggest to simply use the `select` attribute on `xsl:attribute` e.g. `<xsl:attribute name="Oracle_Routing" select="$referenced-node/@OracleSchema"/>`).

If wanted, you can also store all three attributes with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="atts" as="attribute()*" select="key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc)/(@OracleSchema, @DestinationTable, @ColumnName)"/>` and then use e.g. `<xsl:attribute name="Oracle_Routing" select="$atts[1]"/>` although that will need then two code changes if you add or remove an attribute and the index of one changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've tested the second "as=attribute" and I noticed is the indexing does not correspond to the attribute order on the lookup. The Index order appear to map to the order they are found in the lookup document?

Comment: Do you get the order you want if you use `<xsl:variable name="atts" as="attribute()*" select="for $e in key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc) return ($e/@OracleSchema, $e/@DestinationTable, $e/@ColumnName)"/>` instead? You might want to edit your question with some sample data to demonstrate the problem. The `/` sorts the right hand side in document order  so depending on your input data (are there several elements found by that key call?) you might get different results with the two approaches.